# How to access the properties of a component from another component which lies on same page? AEM Java Sling

Tags: java, aem, sling

Assume We have component A and Component B on Home page of AEM instance.
I want Component A properties value on Component B in sling java class.

Can you please provide some code to explain your answer. It would be easy for me to understand

Comment: It really depends, but you can in component A inject currentPage and then get content resource (if it's the fixed path) from component B and get props (getValueMap) or adapt the resource to your sling model.
If it's not a fixed path then you can "search" for the resource type of component B inside the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    // ArrayList<Resource> childList = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    Resource childResource = resource.getParent();
    if (childResource != null) {
        Iterator<Resource> children = childResource.listChildren();
        while (children.hasNext()) {
            Resource child = children.next();
            String parentNodeName = child.getName();
            if (parentNodeName.equals("component-a")) {
                // childList.add(child); 
                title = child.getValueMap().get("headline", "headline value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assigned Component A property(**headline**) value to Component B property(**title**)